# Problem with Backbone.js fetch() on a Collection

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Still struggling to learn Backbone. Currently, my views aren't rendering at all due to some unknown, unreported error that's happening after I call `.fetch()` on my Backbone Collection. Since this can come from any place in my application, I've set up a gist for you to view all the files.

[Link to all the code.](https://gist.github.com/239a2c3a3e66e15d16c1)

The comments in the view should explain the errors that are happening and also the response from the server (which is simply just Sinatra + Redis). The response from `/schools` is `[{"name":"Foo"},{"name":"Bar"}]`, but I don't see why that would cause an error. My view is never initialized for some reason, even though I create a `new window.fooView` in my router. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you never call your view's `render` method.  You should do this explicitly in router.js line 8 or at the end of index.js `initialize` line 12.  Some folks like to automatically render the view after `initialize`, but by default backbone expects you to do it explicitly whenever you want.  I think your `schools.bind` will do this for SUBSEQUENT changes, but the way the code runs, you fetch the schools, which fires events, and THEN you make your view and bind it, so by the time your view is bound, no more events fire, and thus `render` doesn't get called.  A working example would be easier to debug for sure, but that's my guess by reading the gist.

Comment: So the _.bind('all', render) is completely useless? I thought that would call the render method whenever the view object is inferred (in this case, in the router's `new window.fooView`). Instead of binding it, would the correct way be just to call it directly from initialize (as opposed to doing `new window.fooView.render`)?

Comment: No, it's not entirely useless.  It will render the view if you change the collection (like calling fetch again or doing add/remove), but the problem is the order your code is running. Because fetch is called BEFORE you have bound things, it goes 1. fetch called 2. collection events fire 3. you bind to collection events, but oops they already fired so nothing happens right away.  If you move your fetch call into router.js `index` after you've created the view object, then it should start working.  Either that or call `render` explicitly the first time.

Comment: Here's a good example to follow: http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/02/09/backbone.js-tutorial-with-rails-part-2/  Notice how he calls `render` at the end of his `initialize` method.

Comment: Stopping at the debugger statement and calling `new window.schools` gives me a TypeError for `called_non_callable`, which makes no sense given my collection is nearly empty. Is there any relation between the view and this error?